# Keras RNN issue

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network, sequential

have updated the code with full traceback
I am learning to build simple rnn with dense layers because of this issue I have to use TensorFlow which is giving depreciate issue. 
I am following the methods from keras documentation

## Importing the Keras libraries and packages

````
`from keras.models import Sequential`
`from keras.layers import Dense`
`from keras.layers import LSTM`
`from keras.layers import Dropout`

# Initialising the RNN
`regressor = Sequential()`

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
`regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))`
`regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))`
```python
```

>Using TensorFlow backend.
>ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
>Below is the traceback from this internal error.

>Traceback (most recent call last):
 > File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
 >   exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  >File "<ipython-input-3-e62d16493c5f>", line 37, in <module>
   > from keras.models import Sequential
  >File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in ><module>
 >   from . import utils
  >File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line >6, in <module>
 >   from . import conv_utils
  >File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", >line 9, in <module>
 >   from .. import backend as K
  >File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", >line 1, in <module>
 >   from .load_backend import epsilon
  >File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
 >   from .tensorflow_backend import *
  >File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
 >   import tensorflow as tf
  >File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line >98, in <module>
 >   from tensorflow_core import *
  >File "C:\Users\Samra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", >line 42, in <module>
 >   from . _api.v2 import audio
>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core._api.v2'
````

Comment: Facing issue when I am trying to initialize rnn. tried to uninstall TensorFlow and updating Keras didn't work out.

Comment: Can you include a code piece that fully reproduces the problem (including imports), as well as the full traceback?

Comment: https://keras.io/backend/ found the solution